# 3 way chandelier wiring 2 black wires

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to install a chandelier which comes with 2 black wires and a ground of course.  The box is at the end of a 3 way run with a white, a black, a red and a ground.  I know what to do with the ground.

Do I connect one black to the red and the other black to the black and cap the white? or 
Do I connect both the red and black to one of the blacks and the white to the other black?

Comment: What type are the black wires are they a flat cable? Or 2 separate black wires? But there should only be 2 wires that connected to the original light how was that hooked up?

Comment: Flat cable.  One side is ribbed I assume to maintain polarity.

Comment: The flat wire and silver bare ground travel up through a chain.

Comment: The neutral wire is the side with the rib on the 2 conductor flat wire that is normally the white and the other side is the hot , how was the original fixture wired ?   Were the black and red tied together then to the black of the original and the white to the original fixtures white?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: /Users/barryhaley/Desktop/IMG_2607.jpg

Comment: I can't remember how the original was wired.  I tried the red to the ribbed black and the black to the smooth black just caping the white.  Didn't work.  Will try red, black and smooth black

Comment: OK!  Trial and error!  Black capped. White to ribbed neutral. Red to smooth fixture black.  Thanks.